# Component de graficos para React Native?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, redux

Olá eu sou novo no desenvolvimento com react native, existe algum bom componente gráfico para a plataforma?

Comment: fale em português...

Comment: Este portal é em português, se quer ajuda, fale em português.

Comment: Ola eu sou novo no desenvolvimento com react native, existe algum bom componente gráfico para a plataforma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já utilizei [este componente](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts) de gráficos. É bem simples e útil.

Abaixo de implementação:

```
import React from 'react'
import { LineChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'

class LineChartExample extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {

        const data = [ 50, 10, 40, 95, -4, -24, 85, 91, 35, 53, -53, 24, 50, -20, -80 ]

        return (
            <LineChart
                style={{ height: 200 }}
                data={ data }
                svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }}
                contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
            >
               <Grid/>
            </LineChart>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Vinicius, muito obrigado pela resposta vou dar uma olhada neste. : )

Comment: Removi a parte em inglês pois este site é todo em português (se a pergunta foi colocada em inglês por engano, ainda sim não justifica responder em inglês). Outro detalhe é que seria interessante colocar ao menos algum código ou explicação de como usar o componente, pois respostas que só tem um link [não são consideradas boas respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/706/112052). Se for só pra deixar um link, faça-o pelos comentários - isso evita inclusive eventuais negativos, que aliás não fui quem deu :-)